# BufferedImage from 4-bit data buffer

Tags: java, image-processing, awt, bufferedimage, raster

Hello I have a problem with converting my 4-bit data buffer to WritableRaster.
Image resolution: 1024x768 (786432)

Here is description what I'm doing.

1) Create 4-bit BufferedImage

```
bit4Image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, MY_BIT_4_COLOR_MODEL);
Graphics graphics = bit4Image.getGraphics();
graphics.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
graphics.dispose();
//4-bit BufferedImage created. 4-bit BufferedImage is properly made cause it can be saved to hdd and looks good
```

2) Get byte array from DataBuffer from 4-bit

```
byte[] pixelData = ((DataBufferByte)  bit4Image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
// pixelData length is 393216
```

3) Now I want to create BufferedImage from this byte array pixelData

```
BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, MY_BIT_4_COLOR_MODEL);
DataBufferByte buffer = new DataBufferByte(pixelData, pixelData.length);
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(buffer, width, height, width, 1, new int[]{0}, new Point(0, 0));
dest.setData(raster);
```

Problem is when I call `Raster.createInterleavedRaster`.  Exception:
**`java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: Data array too small (should be > 786431 )`**

I also tried something like this

```
BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, MY_BIT_4_COLOR_MODEL);
dest.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, pixelData);
```

But this one gives me similar failure:
  **`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 393216`**

Could someone give me a hint or show the proper way of setting this 4-bit pixelData to WritableRaster?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.
I just had to create WritableRaster with giving it SampleModel:

`SampleModel sm = MY_BIT_4_COLOR_MODEL.createCompatibleSampleModel(width, height);
WritableRaster wr = Raster.createWritableRaster(sm, buffer, new Point(0,0));`

Answer (score 0):

The initial code you had almost worked, the only problem is you tried to create an "interleaved" raster. For palette images (`IndexColorModel`) you typically have only one sample (the palette index) per pixel, so there's no samples to interleave.

Instead, your pixel data is 4 bit/pixel, stored as two pixels per byte. Storing more samples per storage unit, is often referred to as "packed". This means you need to create a "packed" raster, using one of the `Raster.createPackedRaster` methods.

Here's a full, runnable sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int width = 100;
        int height = 100;

        // Create initial 4 bit image
        IndexColorModel icm = new IndexColorModel(4, 16, new int[16], 0, false, -1, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
        BufferedImage bit4Image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, icm);

        // ...you probably do something in between here

        // Get the pixel data
        byte[] pixelData = ((DataBufferByte) bit4Image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

        // ...you probably do something in between here

        // Create a data buffer around the array, wrap in raster
        DataBufferByte buffer = new DataBufferByte(pixelData, pixelData.length);
        WritableRaster raster = Raster.createPackedRaster(buffer, width, height, 4, null);

        // Finally create a copy of the image, sharing pixel data
        BufferedImage copy = new BufferedImage(icm, raster, icm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
        System.out.println("copy: " + copy);
    }
```